# Fanotify access permission event for all files in a directory

Tags: linux, fs, fanotify

I want to get notify for each time a file is accessed in a certain directory using fanotify. I'm familiar with fanotify and generally know how to do it, my problem is with `fanotify_mark` function and what flags and mask should I use for this? I must use `FAN_ACCESS_PERM` flag for permission events, and probably `FAN_MARK_ADD` mask. what other masks should I use? I think it's documentation is very bad and not clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

Fanotify isn't recursive. It only works that way when working on mounted directories.

then in code:

```
fanotify_mark(fd,
      FAN_MARK_ADD | FAN_MARK_MOUNT,
      FAN_ACCESS_PERM | FAN_EVENT_ON_CHILD,
      AT_FDCWD, "/your-directory")
```

All access events on the same mountpoint of /your-directory will be notified.